# Pass a string to another class in real time

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three classes, StartButton class, NewRideAlert and HomeScreen.

StartButton class returns a button that change the String driverState (online or offline).

NewRideAlert class has a timer that at every two seconds show the alert if the user state is setted to online.

HomeScreen class calls StartButton and NewRideAlert classes.

The problem is that i cant pass the string driverState to NewRideAlert in real time, the app runs perfectly, but the NewRideAlert class cant recognize if i change the string driverState, so i have to update the code with hot reload or CTRL + S, then it recognizes.

How can i pass the string value in real time?

StartButton class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StartButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const StartButton({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  StartButtonState createState() => StartButtonState();
}

class StartButtonState extends State<StartButton> {
  static String driverState = 'offline';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _start() {
      return FlatButton(
               child: Text(
                 'Start',
               ),
               onPressed: () {
                 setState(() {
                 if (driverState == 'offline') {
                   driverState = 'online';
                 } else {
                   driverState = 'offline';
                 }
             });
          },
        ),
      );
    }

    return _start();
  }
}
```

NewRideAlert class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'start_button.dart';

class NewRideAlert extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  NewRideAlertState createState() => NewRideAlertState();
}

class NewRideAlertState extends State<NewRideAlert> {
  bool _showAlert = false;

  Future<bool> _getTime() async =>
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        return _showAlert = true;
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    _newRideAlert() {
      return Text('Alert');
    }

    _showAlertLogic() {
      if (StartButtonState.driverState == 'online') {
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: _getTime(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (_showAlert == true) {
              return _newRideAlert();
            } else {
              return Container(
                width: 0.0,
                height: 0.0,
              );
            }
          },
        );
      } else {
        return Container(
          width: 0.0,
          height: 0.0,
        );
      }
    }

    return _showAlertLogic();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with state management, for example the provider package. There is an example in the official documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple